# Query in query for Widget

Tags: widgets, query

I have the following code that works on a page, for listing attachments that are set in a 'folder' by folder ID using another plugin. but when I try to place this in my widget code, it doesn't work.

```
$meta_key1      = get_field('bestandsmap');

$postids=$wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
"
SELECT      afsr_realmedialibrary_posts.attachment
FROM        afsr_realmedialibrary_posts
WHERE       afsr_realmedialibrary_posts.fid = %s

",
$meta_key1
) ); 

if ( $postids ) 
{
echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $postids as $ida ) 
{ 

    $post = get_post( intval( $ida ) );
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $path = wp_get_attachment_url( $ida );
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $fpath; ?> " rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>  
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php

} 
echo "</ul>";
}else{ echo 'Geen bestanden'; }
```

I added the following to get the right id for $meta_key:

```
$meta_key   = get_field('bestandsmap', $customid);
```

When I echo this, I see the proper ID in the widget. But from the $postids=... and downwards the widget is not working/stoping all following widgets from working.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,

Martijn